# Finite differences coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, finite-differences

I'm interested in deriving a forward finite difference approximation for the gradient of a function, $f(x)$, at the point $x = x_i$ using $k+1$ points. If the spatial domain is uniformly discretized, i.e., $x_i = x_0 + i \Delta x, \ \Delta x = X/N$, where $X$ is the length of the domain and $N+1$ is the number of nodes; then, it is well known that the coefficients, $\alpha_j$, of the approximation:

$$f'_i \approx \alpha_0 f_i + \alpha_1 f_{i+1} + \ldots + \alpha_k f_{i+k}, $$ are the solution of a linear system of equations for $\alpha_j$ which comes up from Taylor expansions of the $f_{i+j}$ terms. If a uniform mesh cannot be considered, i.e., $x_i = x_0 + \tilde{\Delta} x_i,  \ \tilde{\Delta} x_i = x_i-x_0$, the resulting system of equations looks like (if I have made no mistakes):

$$  \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots  & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & \Delta  x_1 & \Delta  x_2 & \cdots  & \Delta  x_{k-1} & \Delta  x_k \\
 0 & \Delta  x_1^2 & \Delta  x_2^2 & \cdots  & \Delta  x_{k-1}^2 & \Delta  x_k^2 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 0 & \Delta  x_1^{k-1} & \Delta  x_2^{k-1} & \cdots  & \Delta  x_{k-1}^{k-1} & \Delta  x_k^{k-1} \\
 0 & \Delta  x_1^k & \Delta  x_2^k & \cdots  & \Delta  x_{k-1}^k & \Delta  x_k^k \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \alpha _0 \\
 \alpha _1 \\
 \alpha _2 \\
 \vdots  \\
 \alpha _{k-1} \\
 \alpha _k \\
\end{array}
\right)  =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
 \vdots  \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ where I have not typed the $\tilde{}$ symbol over the $\Delta x $'s for the sake of symplicity.

My questions are: has this system a unique solution for every $k$ and every choice of $\Delta x_i$ or, in other words, is the coefficients matrix always invertible? Has it a recognizable shape (a slightly modified version of Vandermonde's matrix, perhaps)? Would it be more advantageous applying a usual finite difference scheme on a uniform grid (result of transformation of the actual mesh) than solving this system of equations?

Any thoughts or piece of advice will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is unique if all increments are different from each other, this is a fundamental fact about Vandermonde matrices. An explicit solution can be given via the Lagrange interpolation formula, 
$$
p(t)=\sum_{j=0}^kf(x_{i+j})\prod_{m\ne j}\frac{x_0+t-x_m}{x_j-x_m}
$$
with derivative in $t=0$ of
$$
p'(0)=f(x_i)\sum_{m\ne 0}\frac1{x_0-x_m}+\sum_{j=1}^kf(x_{i+j})\frac1{x_j-x_0}
$$

Comment: Of course, all the increments are differents, since they are defined as $x_i - x_0$ and $x_i \neq x_j, \, \forall i,j$. This is a nice approach. Thanks!